# wget Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: javascript, html, wget

Пытаюсь скопировать такой командой, но выдает ошибку
      wget --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge -v --debug https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_63381_v1

```
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.11.4 on Windows-MSVC.

--2018-05-20 10:19:51--  https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_63381_v1
Resolving ld-wp.template-help.com... seconds 0.00, 213.239.221.101
Caching ld-wp.template-help.com => 213.239.221.101
Connecting to ld-wp.template-help.com|213.239.221.101|:443... seconds 0.00, connected.
Created socket 596.
Releasing 0x0226ed28 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
Closed fd 596
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня wget 1.19 и ваш запрос отрабатывает нормально.

Попробуйте обновиться: https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

```
$  wget --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge -v --debug https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_63381_v1
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.4 on mingw32.

Reading HSTS entries from d:\wget/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = 'CP1251'
converted 'https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_63381_v1' (CP1251) -> 'https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_63381_v1' (UTF-8)
Converted file name 'wordpress_63381_v1' (UTF-8) -> 'wordpress_63381_v1' (CP1251)
--2018-05-20 10:38:59--  https://ld-wp.template-help.com/wordpress_63381_v1
Resolving ld-wp.template-help.com (ld-wp.template-help.com)... seconds 0,00, 213.239.221.101
Caching ld-wp.template-help.com => 213.239.221.101
Connecting to ld-wp.template-help.com (ld-wp.template-help.com)|213.239.221.101|:443... seconds 0,00, connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x00000000008bafd0 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
seconds 900,00, Winsock error: 0
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x00000000008c9470
certificate:
  subject: CN=ld-wp.template-help.com
  issuer:  CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host ld-wp.template-help.com

---request begin---
GET /wordpress_63381_v1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.19.4 (mingw32)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Host: ld-wp.template-help.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... seconds 900,00, Winsock error: 0
No data received.
Closed 3/SSL 0x00000000008c9470
Retrying.
```